# Show that $g'(x)+g(x)-2e^x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given a function $g$ which has derivative $g'$ for all x $\in {R}$ and satisfying $g'(0)=2$ and $g(x+y)=e^yg(x)+e^xg(y)$ for all $x,y\in {R}$
>
> Show that $g'(x)+g(x)-2e^x=0$

$\dfrac{g(x+y)}{e^{x+y}}=\dfrac{g(x)}{e^{x}}+\dfrac{g(y)}{e^{y}}$

Putting $x=0$,

$g'(y)=2e^y+g(x)$

Also putting $y=0$,we get,

$0=e^xg(0)\implies g(0)=0$

I had a strong hunch that $g(x)=e^x-e^{-x}$ but it does not satisfy $g(x+y)=e^yg(x)+e^xg(y)$

Please help.

Comment: is this $g'(x) - g(x) - 2e^x =0?$

Comment: No it is not. This is what is given.

Comment: Define $f(x) = \frac{g(x)}{e^x}$. Now it's given that $f$ is additive and continous (because differentiable everywhere), so $f(x) = ax$ for some constant $a$, and thus $g(x) = axe^x$ for some constant $a$. Now you should fill up the remaining details

Comment: @AlexKChen: solving for $a$ with the criterion $g'(0) = 2$ gives $a = 2$ and thus $g'(x) - g(x) - 2e^x = 0$, not $g'(x) + g(x)$ as the question says, so I suspect that the OP was given an  incorrect question.

Comment: No @ConnorHarris I also found out the same result as yours but this was given in a National Level Entrance Test in India. I am sure the question is not wrong.

Comment: @Saradamani Would you mind sharing the link from where the question came from. Something ain't right here.

Comment: I will directly take a snapshot then for you all.

Comment: @AlexKChen Not JEE. I have passed JEE long before in 2009. I have completed all those horrible things . This is for admission to Quality Management Science at Indian Statistical Institute.

Comment: Please see the edit in the OP @imranfat I have directly given the snapshot of the problem.

Comment: @Saradamani When I consider $g^{'}(x)+g(x)-2e^x=0$ purely as a differential equation, I can solve it to find the solution  $g(x)=Ae^{-x} + 2xe^{-x}$. That is not an answer to your question but...the solution does not work for what is to be proven. That's what I meant by "something ain't right here. I tend to go with Bill's answer

Comment: @imranfat ISI people are nowadays giving wrong questions! Then I was right from the beginning Yipee!

Answer (score 2):

Let $h(x)=\frac{g(x)}{e^x}$. Then, $h'(x)=\frac{g'(x)e^x-g(x)e^x}{e^{2x}}$.

Note that you wrote $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$.

Then, $h'(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \frac{h(x+\epsilon)-h(x)}{\epsilon}=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{h(\epsilon)}{\epsilon}=h'(0)=2$ whatever $x\in\mathbb{R}$ since you noted that $h(0)=g(0)=0$.

then $h'(x)=\frac{g'(x)e^x-g(x)e^x}{e^{2x}}$ becomes $2e^x+g(x)=g'(x)$. Any chance that sign was the other way?

Comment: This is what I also wonder @Bill O'Haran as I got the same result but that is exactly where I wonder.

Comment: Well, since everything leads to it, I think we should accept there was a typo.

Comment: @BillO'Haran I think you are correct

Comment: Also, just to make sure @Saradamani, you thought that $g(x)=e^x-e^{-x}$ but you do realize that you are not asked to find $g$ but prove the desired equality whatever $g$ verifying the morphism property? Just making sure we are on the same page.

Comment: @BillO'Haran I thought it so because $g^{'}(0)=2$ and $g(0)=0$ as shown which gives us the perfect notion(or hunch) if you call it because I could not find out anything fruitious empirically hence I had to resort to this hunch but what I showed empirically is the same result you obtained. But you see if $g(x)=e^x-e^{-x}$, it satisfies $g^{'}(x)+g(x)-2e^x=0$.That is why that hunch. Am I completely understood now?

Answer (score 1):

$$g(x+y) = e^y g(x) + e^x g(y)$$
Differentiating w.r.t. y
$$g'(x+y) = e^y g(x) + e^x g'(y)$$
Now put $y=0$
$$g'(x) = e^0 g(x) + e^x g'(0)\implies g'(x) - g(x) - 2e^x = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

As noted in question and one other answer, with $h(x)=e^{-x}g(x)$ you get $h$ differentiable at $x=0$ and $h(x+y)=h(x)+h(y)$. This is one of Cauchy's fundamental functional equations with solution $h(x)=ax$. Now insert to $g(x)=axe^x$ and compare the derivatives $g'(x)=a(1+x)e^x$ at $x=0$, $2=g'(0)=a$, to get the unique solution.

---

Setting $x=0$ in the original equation gives
$$
g(y)=e^yg(0)+g(y)\implies g(0)=0
$$
Computing the $x$-derivative and then setting $x=0$ results in
$$
g'(x+y)=e^yg'(x)+e^xg(y)\implies
g'(y)=e^yg'(0)+g(y)\implies g'(y)-g(y)-2e^y=0
$$
which has one sign different than the ODE that you obtained.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in other answers/comments, if $g'(x)\color{red}{-}g(x)-2e^x=0, g'(0)=2$, then:
$$g(x)=2xe^x \Rightarrow g(x+y)=e^yg(x)+e^xg(y).$$